# Access CI POST array without extra variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to access a posted array value without an extra variable in CodeIgniter?

Example:

POST data:

```
data[1]=abc&data[2]=bcd&data[3]=dca
```

Model/Controller, retrieve first value ("abc"):

Test 1:

```
$first = $this->input->post('data')[1]; // doesn't work
```

**EDIT:** Test 1 works, I had a typo when I tried...

Test 2:

```
$first = $this->input->post('data[1]'); // doesn't work
```

Test 3:

```
$data  = $this->input->post('data'); // add post array to variable
$first = $data[1]; // works...
```

Can I avoid the extra step?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense that Test 1 wouldn't work and Test 3 does...

Comment: It does, depending on php version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should definitely work:

```
$first  = $this->input->post('data')[1];
```

It's an array, there is no big difference between your Test 1 and Test 3, You should be able to access `[1]` in both cases.

The only scenario that this would not work is if you are using php version bellow 5.4:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Comment: If you have at least php5.4

Answer (score 2):

Test 1 works for PHP 5.4+ (function array dereferencing)

You could also do

```
list($first, $second, $third) =  $this->input->post('data');
```